# minus time fromcalculated time difference query

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

i am facing an issue with my query i store users login time_in and time_out and a column name called break where i manually enter how long user has been on break supposing an hour then 01:00:00 i store it on the break column and to get total login hours of a user i use

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in)) AS totalhours
```

now from the above query how can i subtract the value i store it on break column and then show the total hours?  only if break column has some value then subtract else show the correct total hours.

e.g if say users total login hours is 9hrs but then in break i added 1hr then the totalhours instead of showing 9hrs should rather display 8hrs.

here is my complete query

```
SELECT hours_id,
       member_id,
       username,
       team,
       time_in,
       time_out,
       break,
       activity,
       comments,
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_ink)) AS totalhours
FROM login_hours
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '".$filter_date."'
ORDER BY activity DESC
```

Really appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: Provide a sample (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with some data) and show desired output for this data with explanations.

Comment: PS. `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_ink))` may be replaced with `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ..)` - it will be more clear I think.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it by

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in)) - TIME_TO_SEC(break) AS totalhours
```

it does gives the result im looking for. can someone tell me if its right?